# Has anybody encountered (and solved) problem with video textures in animation?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, materials

**The problem:**

I have an animation, that uses videos as textures of background materials. With one specific video, when rendering with cycles, in random frames the texture glitches out, showing either as black, glitchy noise, texture misaligned or completely different texture that is used in the same animation. With other videos it has been fine. But - as it commonly happens in such weird cases - client really likes THAT video as a background :)

Edit: remembered a thing that may be relevant. The glitches happen usually on single object. So another one using same texture may be totally fine in this frame, but glitch in another.

In addition to this, in 2.93 other non-animated textures glitched out too - but much less frequently. In this case, group of objects (parented to single empty) showed up as totally black in single frame. These objects have all different shaders.

2.92 - lots of animated texture glitches, no nonanimated texture glithces.

2.93 - somewhat fewer animated texture glitches, but some nonanimated ones.

**Additional info:**
Rendering settings: cycles, optix, gpu only; 128 samples, optix denoising, tile size 256x256 px

Gpu: Quadro RTX 3000

Animation length: 900 frames, output resolution 1920x1080

Animated materials themselves are pretty simple: image node (using video as texture) > color curves node > emission shader. Video lengths are 300-800 frames. Resolutions are different for different videos, but also quite small
There are 8 objects with animated materials playing in loop, that use 4 different textures (the textures are same in some materials, just offset playing times so that it wouldnt that much visible that same texture is used.

Nonanimated materials are different types of metal, with separate texture images for roughness, normals, and color.

Animation itself is animated character dancing on a table in fancy club or pub style atmosphere. Sadly cannot add images or file due NDA

**What I have tried:**

Tried rendering in 2.92 and 2.93

Updated graphics drivers.

Re-Output the same offending video in AfterEffects: imported it in AE composition as a layer and rendered the composition with different size and aspect ratio, then used the new video as a texture.

Tried rendering in cpu only - that actually (probably) helped, but with the current complexity, it would take a week or more continous rendering to output one single animation, and I have several scenarios. So this will not work.

So - has anybody encountered something similar ?

Comment: My “guess” would be GPU memory issues. Can you try simplifying your textures to lower resolution (so they take up less memory) and retry to see if this helps?

Comment: and what about outputing the videos as image sequences instead?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The animations are pretty low resolution (stock video preview versions, at this stage), so resolution is probably not an issue. Actually thought of using images myself, during the lunch, will try that out next. Thanks again :)

Comment: Long time later, but just to recap, so if somebody runs into something similar, they can use this solution: For animated texture glitches, having the video texture in separate frame .png-s instead of single video frame indeed helped. For non-animated texture glitches, the problem seemed to be some bugs in  2.93 - so while similar, its probably totally separate issue. I just used 2.92 to render out the stuff.